# Polygon Selection in Manual Editing (eCognition)

Tags: polygon, editing, ecognition

eCognition software allows manual editing on segments with the options such as"polygon selection, line selection, rectangle selection and cut object manually". In my study, polygon selection option does not work correctly when determining a boundary and just emphasizes the current segment. So, a new edited closed area cannot be created manually but "cut object manually" works correctly. Is there any setting to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

there should be a toolbar of manual editing and then you can select a new class then click an object which means you are assigning a new classification on it.